# Out of bounds address when overriding virtual class method in cuda kernel

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, cuda, overriding

For the project I'm working on, I have defined a certain base class and several derived classes that inherit it. The base class has several virtual methods that are overriden by methods in the derived classes.
At a certain point I need to pass a (derived) custom class instantiation to a kernel and use one of the custom class' methods inside said kernel. Using the method (hopefully) does not modify the object. I have tried to adapt the following C++ minimum working example so that it works on arrays:

```
#include<iostream>

class basefoo{
    public:
    virtual int getiden(int i){return 0;}
};

class derivefoo : public basefoo{
    public:
    int getiden(int i){return i;}
};

int getsq(basefoo *foo, int q){
    int result = (foo->getiden(q))*(foo->getiden(q));
    return result;
}

int main(){
    derivefoo foo;
    basefoo foo2;
    int q=3;
    std::cout<<getsq(&foo, q)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<getsq(&foo2, q)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
9
0
```

as expected.

My minimum CUDA example is the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class basefoo{
    public:
    basefoo(){}
    __host__ __device__ virtual int getiden(int i){return 0;}
};

class derivefoo : public basefoo{
    public:
    derivefoo(){}
    __host__ __device__ int getiden(int i){return i;}
};

__global__ void get_squares(int* squares, basefoo *foo, int sroot, int nsq){
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    if(tid < nsq){
        squares[tid] = 0;
        int result = (foo->getiden(sroot))*(foo->getiden(sroot));
        squares[tid] += result;
    }
}

int main(){
    int sroot = 4;
    int nsquares = 2;
    int *hsquares, *dsquares;
    hsquares = (int *)malloc(nsquares*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&dsquares, nsquares*sizeof(int));

    basefoo foo, *dfoo;
    derivefoo foo2, *dfoo2;

    cudaMalloc(&dfoo, sizeof(basefoo));
    cudaMemcpy(dfoo, &foo, sizeof(basefoo), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc(&dfoo2, sizeof(derivefoo));
    cudaMemcpy(dfoo2, &foo2, sizeof(derivefoo), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    get_squares<<<1, 2>>>(dsquares, dfoo, sroot, nsquares);
    cudaMemcpy(hsquares, dsquares, nsquares*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%d %d \n", hsquares[0], hsquares[1]);

    get_squares<<<1, 2>>>(dsquares, dfoo2, sroot, nsquares);
    cudaMemcpy(hsquares, dsquares, nsquares*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%d %d \n", hsquares[0], hsquares[1]);


    return 0;

}
```

When executing it with compute-sanitizer --tool memcheck I get several out of bounds errors (5 for this minimum example). Here is the first one:

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4 bytes
=========     at 0xc8 in get_squares(int *, basefoo *, int, int)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x555f56399068 is out of bounds
=========     and is 45,900,972,322,712 bytes before the nearest allocation at 0x7f1e7d600000 of size 8 bytes
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame: [0x32e130]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:libcudart_static_4d8b33a106dceb3c07a56e26de61f2d53bb62a68 [0x1091e]
=========                in /home/arin/Desktop/cuda codes/ASMD/./inhtest
=========     Host Frame:cudaLaunchKernel [0x70b2e]
=========                in /home/arin/Desktop/cuda codes/ASMD/./inhtest
=========     Host Frame:cudaError cudaLaunchKernel<char>(char const*, dim3, dim3, void**, unsigned long, CUstream_st*) [0xb1ba]
=========                in /home/arin/Desktop/cuda codes/ASMD/./inhtest
=========     Host Frame:__device_stub__Z11get_squaresPiP7basefooii(int*, basefoo*, int, int) [0xafec]
=========                in /home/arin/Desktop/cuda codes/ASMD/./inhtest
=========     Host Frame:get_squares(int*, basefoo*, int, int) [0xb036]
=========                in /home/arin/Desktop/cuda codes/ASMD/./inhtest
=========     Host Frame:main [0xad1d]
=========                in /home/arin/Desktop/cuda codes/ASMD/./inhtest
=========     Host Frame:../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:__libc_start_call_main [0x29d90]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame:../csu/libc-start.c:379:__libc_start_main [0x29e40]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame:_start [0xaae5]
=========                in /home/arin/Desktop/cuda codes/ASMD/./inhtest
```

It's worth noting that there are no memcheck errors at all if I delete the "virtual" keyword in basefoo's getiden method, but then the override isn't successful, and I need it for my project.Does anyone have any idea of what is causing this?
This is CUDA 12.2 in Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: I have never used cuda, but will this work for non-trivially-copyable types? `cudaMalloc(&dfoo, sizeof(basefoo)); cudaMemcpy(dfoo, &foo, sizeof(basefoo), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); cudaMalloc(&dfoo2, sizeof(derivefoo)); cudaMemcpy(dfoo2, &foo2, sizeof(derivefoo), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);`?  In C++, you can't simply treat these types as if they are the same as `int`, `double` etc.

Comment: Agreed. This allocates memory, but actually fails to construct the C++ objects.

Comment: vtables between host and device are not compatible. you need to construct derived objects on the device.

Comment: This seems to be no different than if you were trying to marshal those objects over a socket, or tried to write those objects to a file, etc.  You can't simply treat those objects as a blob of bytes -- you have to somehow send or marshal the *data* that those objects represents, and on the receiving side, the receiver takes that data and recreates those objects.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The C++ example works, so it seems like the C++ objects are getting constructed at least there. If they aren't getting constructed, which would be the proper way to do it? And if they are, why doesn't it work for the host objects in CUDA?

Comment: @AbatorAbetor Thank you, I wasn't aware of this. How could I do it?

Comment: @cyanmess -- `The C++ example works,` -- That is because nowhere in that example are you treating `basefoo` or `derivefoo` as trivially-copyable.  Put a `std::string` member in `basefoo` and fill that `std::string` with 1000 characters.  What do you believe `sizeof(basefoo)` will be in the cuda version?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't know. I have only few months of experience with CUDA and no experience working with custom classes. My first intuition is 1000*sizeof(char), but for the above reasons, I believe it is wrong. What will it be?

Comment: @cyanmess -- [See this example](https://godbolt.org/z/h7eYa5hd3).  No matter how many characters you set the `std::string`, to the `sizeof(basefoo)` is the same.  So how would have the `sizeof(basefoo)` had worked in the cuda call if the result will always be 32 (or whatever compile-time constant that sizeof() will produce)?  Remember that `sizeof()` is a *compile-time* value, that literally gives you the number of bytes that **type** occupies.  The type is `basefoo`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer could be found in the [CUDA documentation about virtual functions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#virtual-functions):

> If an object is created in host code, invoking a virtual function for that object in device code has undefined behavior.

The following code creating object on the device will work

```
#include <iostream>

class basefoo
{
public:
    __host__ __device__ basefoo() {}
    __host__ __device__ virtual int getiden(int i) { return 0; }
};

class derivefoo : public basefoo
{
public:
    __host__ __device__ derivefoo() {}
    __host__ __device__ int getiden(int i) override { return i; }
};

__global__ void get_squares(int* squares, int sroot, int nsq)
{
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    derivefoo dfoo;
    basefoo* bfoo = &dfoo;
    if (tid < nsq)
    {
        squares[tid] = 0;
        int result = (bfoo->getiden(sroot)) * (bfoo->getiden(sroot));
        squares[tid] += result;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sroot = 4;
    int nsquares = 2;
    int *hsquares, *dsquares;
    hsquares = (int *)malloc(nsquares*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&dsquares, nsquares*sizeof(int));

    get_squares<<<1, 2>>>(dsquares, sroot, nsquares);
    cudaMemcpy(hsquares, dsquares, nsquares*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%d %d \n", hsquares[0], hsquares[1]);

    cudaFree(dsquares);
    free(hsquares);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

cudaMemcpy* will transfer the vtable between host and device. In general, host pointers are invalid on the device, and vice-versa. To be usable on the device, objects with virtual functions must be constructed on the device to set up valid function pointers.

To make a copied object usable on the destination (cpu or gpu), one can copy-construct the object in-place, using placement-new.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{
    __host__ __device__
    virtual int compute() = 0;
};

struct Bar : public Foo{
    int x = 1;
    __host__ __device__
    int compute() override{
        return x + 2;
    }
};

__global__
void computeKernel(Foo* object){
    int result = object->compute();
    printf("result %d\n", result);
}

__global__
void fixBarObject(Bar* b){
    new (b) Bar(*b);
}

int main(){
    Bar b;
    b.x = 3;

    Bar* d_b;
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, sizeof(Bar));
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, sizeof(Bar), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    fixBarObject<<<1,1>>>(d_b);
    computeKernel<<<1,1>>>(d_b);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Output: `result 5`